# Debugging VBA for Workbooks password protection

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to password-protect multiple Excel workbooks in one folder with pre-defined unique passwords stored in another distinct workbook which is stored separately. Note that password designated for each workbook is different.

I have written below code, but get a run-time error 1004 - This extension cannot be used with the selected file type.

```
Public Sub Protect_with_PWs()

  Dim FSO As Object
  Dim folder As Object, subfolder As Object
  Dim wb As Object
  Dim i As Long, wbcontrol As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

  Set wbcontrol = ThisWorkbook
  Set ws = wbcontrol.ActiveSheet

  Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  folderPath = "C:\Users\sabrina\Documents\VBA-PW\VBA_Password protection"
  Set folder = FSO.GetFolder(folderPath)

  With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .AskToUpdateLinks = False

  End With

  For Each wb In folder.Files
    If Right(wb.Name, 3) = "xls" Or Right(wb.Name, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(wb.Name, 4) = "xlsm" Then
      Set masterWB = Workbooks.Open(wb)
      i = 1
      While ws.Cells(i, 1) <> ""
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ws.Cells(i, 1), Password:=ws.Cells(i, 2)
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        i = i + 1
      Wend
      ActiveWorkbook.Close True

    End If

  Next

  With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .AskToUpdateLinks = True
  End With

End Sub
```

The error is specifically related to this line "ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ws.Cells(i, 1), Password:=ws.Cells(i, 2)". Does anyone know why the error and how to fix it? The cell referred to here contains file names with extension of .xlsx. Greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ws.Cells(i, 1), Password:="password" with a string, does that work? I know it's not a solution, but it would let us know what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes, I have tried that. It's giving me the same error message...

Comment: I believe you need to check the extension and use the corresponding file format parameter: `xlOpenXMLWorkbook`, `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` or `xlWorkbookNormal` depending on the existing extension

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but saving as .xlsb is recommended if you don't want the passwords to be trivially bypassed.

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to achieve here.  You are closing the workbook `ActiveWorkbook.Close` in the loop and then again working with it? I would recommend using objects since you declared them. For example `masterWB.SaveAs...` Avoid the use of `Activeworkbook`